# How to do editing in playing video in iPad

Tags: ios, ipad, avfoundation

i am newbie to ipad programming , i have searched the internet but nothing help .i have to do some editing in video running in iPad application which is of golf play type in which i have to analyze the swing of player. how can i do this?t[image]Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Please check the below tutorial that available in **raywenderlich** blog.

[How to Play, Record, and Edit Videos in iOS](http://www.raywenderlich.com/13418/how-to-play-record-edit-videos-in-ios)

Comment: :i checked all that but there is nothing which can be used for editing .